# c# wpf) indeterminate Progressbar doesn't start spinning animation and even seems to block overall performance

Tags: c#, async-await, progress-bar, backgroundworker, begininvoke

I adopted good person's solution and it's working fine to update the progress as determinate. However, I'm experiencing difficulty to use as an indeterminate one. Rarely, the spinning animation of indeterminate Progressbar shows but very lately.

I'm basic learner and don't know very much about async, backgroundworker(multi threading). So, please kindly forgive my poor knowledgements.

What is different from determinate code of mine is I use `this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(async() =>{...}))` because I encountered An Exception due to await code inside bwDoWork method.

What I'd like to implement is my application runs much faster with showing indeterminate progress bar by main thread and background worker work quickly together.

I'd highly appreaciate someone consults me with excellent insight.

XAML code of progressBar_forBasicWaiting Window is,

```
<Window x:Class="progressBar_forBasicWaiting.ProgressDialog_forBasicWaiting"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Blue Tiger Program v1.0"
    ContentRendered="initBackgroundWorker"
    Height="168.946" Width="518.001" MinHeight="100" MinWidth="350" ResizeMode="NoResize" Background="#FFFFFFFF" BorderThickness="0" WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" Icon="whitecross_icon.ico" ShowInTaskbar="False" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Loaded="Window_Loaded" Visibility="Visible">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="40*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="100*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock x:Name="pbHeader" Margin="0,0,0,1" Padding="5,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
               Text="{Binding Title,RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType=Window}}" 
               FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Black" Background="#FF7BD34E" Opacity="0">
    </TextBlock>
    <ProgressBar Name="pbStatus" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Maximum="100" Value="0" Foreground="#FF65ADF1" Margin="114,10,104,63" BorderThickness="0" IsHitTestVisible="False" IsTabStop="False" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" UseLayoutRounding="True" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="#FFF0F0F0" IsIndeterminate="True" >
        <ProgressBar.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect/>
        </ProgressBar.Effect>
    </ProgressBar>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlockPercentageshow" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding ElementName=pbStatus, Path=Value, StringFormat={}{0:0}%}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="0.627,-1.083" Margin="218,10,213,61" Width="81" IsHitTestVisible="False" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Padding="29,5,0,0" UseLayoutRounding="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Height="26" Visibility="Hidden" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlockProgressbartitle" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="loading data.." VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="494" Height="25" IsHitTestVisible="False" UseLayoutRounding="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Padding="0,3,0,0"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlockMessagewaitplease" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="164,53,156,0" Grid.Row="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="192" Height="32" IsHitTestVisible="False" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" UseLayoutRounding="True" Text="Please wait.." Padding="5,5,0,0"/>
</Grid>
```

behind cs code of progressBar_forBasicWaiting Window is,

```
namespace progressBar_forBasicWaiting {

public partial class ProgressDialog_forBasicWaiting : Window {

    private static BackgroundWorker bw = null;         // Background task handler
    private static string progressHeaderText = "Pending ...";
    private static string progressMessageText = "Starting ...";
    private static int progressPercentage = 0;

    public ProgressDialog_forBasicWaiting() {

        bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bwProgressChanged);
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bwRunWorkerCompleted);

        SetProgressOptions(false, true);         // set cancellation, report-progress states

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void SetProgressOptions(bool can, bool rpt) {
        bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = can;
        bw.WorkerReportsProgress = rpt;
    }

    public void AddDoWorkHandler(Action<object,DoWorkEventArgs> fn) {
        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(fn);
    }

    public void AddProgressChangedHandler(Action<object,ProgressChangedEventArgs> fn) {
        bw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(fn);
    }

    public void AddProgressCompletedHandler(Action<object, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs> fn) {
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(fn);
    }

    public void Start() {
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    public void UpdateProgress(int pct) {
        progressPercentage = pct;
        bw.ReportProgress(pct);
    }

    public void ChangeStatusMessage(string msg) {
        progressMessageText = msg;
        bw.ReportProgress(progressPercentage);
    }

    public void ChangeWindowTitle(string ttl) {
        progressHeaderText = ttl;
        bw.ReportProgress(progressPercentage);
    }

    private void initBackgroundWorker(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void bwProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e) {
        pbHeader.Text = progressHeaderText;
        pbStatus.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }

    private void bwRunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
  }
}
```

starting code from mainWindow is,

```
private async void buttonGreenStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
 pb_forBasicWaiting = new ProgressDialog_forBasicWaiting();                      
 pb_forBasicWaiting.Owner = this;              
 pb_forBasicWaiting.SetProgressOptions(false, true);
 pb_forBasicWaiting.AddDoWorkHandler(bwDoWork);                                                                      

 pb_forBasicWaiting.Show();
}
```

DoWork code from mainWindow is,

```
    void bwDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(async() =>
        {
            string localConnectionString = string.Format(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename= " + Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPDATA") + @"\Blue Tiger" + @"\greendb_{0}.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=False;", textBoxGreenLogin.Text);

            SqlConnection bwConn = new SqlConnection();
            bwConn.ConnectionString = localConnectionString;
            bwConn.Open();

            SqlCommand load_mainpatientslistcomm = new SqlCommand();
            load_mainpatientslistcomm.Connection = bwConn;

            load_mainpatientslistcomm.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT patientid, patientname, registrationdate, birthyear, birthmonth, consultation_count, basicmemo FROM patientslist_pharmacy_{0}_{1}", comboBoxPharmacyid.SelectedItem.ToString(), textBoxGreenLogin.Text);
            load_mainpatientslistcomm.CommandTimeout = 190;

            SqlDataAdapter load_mainpatientslistda = new SqlDataAdapter(load_mainpatientslistcomm);

            static_green_mainpatientslist_dt = new DataTable(string.Format("patientslist_pharmacy_{0}_{1}", comboBoxPharmacyid.SelectedItem.ToString(), textBoxGreenLogin.Text));
            load_mainpatientslistda.Fill(static_green_mainpatientslist_dt);

            byteAESKey = Convert.FromBase64String(static_AESKey);
            byteAESIV = Convert.FromBase64String(static_AESIV);

            foreach (DataRow row in static_green_mainpatientslist_dt.Rows)
            {
                string strpatientname = (string)row["patientname"].ToString();
                bytepatientname = Convert.FromBase64String(strpatientname);
                string decryptedpatientname = Green_MainWindow.DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(bytepatientname, byteAESKey, byteAESIV);

                row["patientname"] = decryptedpatientname;
            }

            bwConn.Close();

            Service1Client client_countidea = new Service1Client();
            int azuregreenideatotalcount = await client_countidea.CountIdeaOnServerAsync();
            client_countidea.Close();

            Service1Client client_countoverview = new Service1Client();
            int azureoverviewtotalcount = await client_countoverview.CountOverviewOnServerAsync();
            client_countoverview.Close();

            Service1Client client_countoverview_tobedeleted = new Service1Client();
            int azureoverviewtotalcount_tobedeleted = await client_countoverview_tobedeleted.CountOverviewTobeDeletedOnServerAsync();
            client_countoverview_tobedeleted.Close();

            if (azureoverviewtotalcount != localoverviewtotalcount)
            {
                if (localoverviewtotalcount == 0)
                {
                    Service1Client client_copyoverviewfromserver = new Service1Client();
                    overviewarray_fromserver = await client_copyoverviewfromserver.OverviewArrayFromServerAsync();

                    client_copyoverviewfromserver.Close();

                    SqlConnection localoverviewupdateConn = new SqlConnection();
                    localoverviewupdateConn.ConnectionString = green_dataConnectionString;
                    localoverviewupdateConn.Open();

                    foreach (string single_overview in overviewarray_fromserver)
                    {
                        SqlCommand localoverviewupdatecomm = new SqlCommand();
                        localoverviewupdatecomm.Connection = localoverviewupdateConn;

                        localoverviewupdatecomm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO overview_keyword (immunity_markers) VALUES(@oimmunity)";

                        var localoverviewupdateda = new SqlDataAdapter(localoverviewupdatecomm);

                        localoverviewupdateda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@oimmunity", SqlDbType.NVarChar));
                        localoverviewupdateda.SelectCommand.Parameters["@oimmunity"].Value = single_overview;

                        var localoverviewupdateds = new DataSet();
                        localoverviewupdateda.Fill(localoverviewupdateds);
                    }
                    localoverviewupdateConn.Close();
                }

                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        SqlDataAdapter localoverviewclearda = new SqlDataAdapter();

                        SqlConnection localoverviewclearConn = new SqlConnection();
                        localoverviewclearConn.ConnectionString = greenpharmacy_dataConnectionString;
                        localoverviewclearConn.Open();

                        string sql = "DELETE FROM overview_keyword";

                        localoverviewclearda.DeleteCommand = localoverviewclearConn.CreateCommand();
                        localoverviewclearda.DeleteCommand.CommandText = sql;
                        localoverviewclearda.DeleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        localoverviewclearConn.Close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                    }

                    Service1Client client_copyoverviewfromserver = new Service1Client();
                    overviewarray_fromserver = await client_copyoverviewfromserver.OverviewArrayFromServerAsync();

                    client_copyoverviewfromserver.Close();

                    SqlConnection localoverviewupdateConn = new SqlConnection();
                    localoverviewupdateConn.ConnectionString = greenpharmacy_dataConnectionString;
                    localoverviewupdateConn.Open();

                    foreach (string single_overview in overviewarray_fromserver)
                    {
                        SqlCommand localoverviewupdatecomm = new SqlCommand();
                        localoverviewupdatecomm.Connection = localoverviewupdateConn;

                        localoverviewupdatecomm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO overview_keyword (immunity_markers) VALUES(@oimmunity)";

                        var localoverviewupdateda = new SqlDataAdapter(localoverviewupdatecomm);

                        localoverviewupdateda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@oimmunity", SqlDbType.NVarChar));
                        localoverviewupdateda.SelectCommand.Parameters["@oimmunity"].Value = single_overview;

                        var localoverviewupdateds = new DataSet();
                        localoverviewupdateda.Fill(localoverviewupdateds);
                    }
                    localoverviewupdateConn.Close();

                }

            }


            else
            {

            }

        }));
        pb_forBasicWaiting.UpdateProgress(100);
    }
```

Comment: Please reduce amount of code and provide a minimum necessary code to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @3615, ok, I'm trying..

Comment: Just an observation. By using Dispatcher.BeginInvoke you are basically saying to execute following code on UI Thread. Operation of filling load_mainpatientslistda would be executed on UI Thread blocking your application untill is executed. Consider using Dispatcher.BeginInvoke only for code that actually interact with UI, all other code should be executed on parallel thread.

Comment: @3615, your comment seems important point. I'm considering to move all the job in bwDoWork to Progressbar Window. It's too complicated for beginner..

Comment: Moving your specific business logic to a generic control like ProgressBar seems to be a bad idea. When you will need 1 more progress bar to show for another window you will be stuck.

Comment: @3615, ok, I'll follow your idea. Now, I'm just removing all the asynchronous job in the bwDoWork to remain some synchronous jobs left only. Could you help me how to run the Operation of filling load_mainpatientslistda to be executed on backgroundworker thread but not UI thread ?? Just using Invoke? not BeginInvoke?

Comment: bwDoWork method executed on bw thread because you tied it up to  bw.DoWork. So unless you are explicitly invoking something on UI Thread by calling Dispatcher.BeginInvoke or Dispatcher.Invoke it's executed on worker thread. Aware that from worker thread you cannot access UI elements, like pb_forBasicWaiting, only calls to them should be wrapped in Dispatcher.BeginInvoke

Comment: @3615, Oh, it's working ! your explanation helped me to understand how background worker works. I removed BeginInvoke and Invoke and changed the direct access to UI element(textBoxGreen.Text) to non UI element..My deepest appreciation to you ! I wish you had posted your opinion as an Answer.

Comment: No problems, I'm glad it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

You are not awaiting the async operation at all. That's the problem. The correct usage on a method that does not return any value is as follow...

```
public async Task MethodName()
{
    await obj.MethodAsync();
}
```

Furthermore, if you are using the PTL's async/await pattern you should be using `async`, `await` everywhere or else use `ConfigureAwait(false)` wherever you can...

Comment: Thanks for your insight. Could you kindly help me because I'm totally entry level to async, await programming. It's too complicated even when it comes to backgroundworker for beginner like me..